# Can't change permissions

Tags: permissions

I have a connected external (usb) hard disk. It appears on my desktop and under Devices in the left column when I open a folder. But when I use the Open File or Save As dialogues from with any program, it doesn't appear. I've found it under File System / media / don / media. But when I try to access that folder through the Open File or Save As dialogues, I get an error message -- Could not read the contents of media, Error opening directory '/media': Permission denied.

When I right-click on that folder through the folders dialogue and go to the Permissions tab, it's all grayed out. At the bottom of that box it says, "You are not the owner so you cannot change these permissions."

There are no other accounts on this computer, only me. How do I make everything available to me all the time?

Comment: If it is formatted as NTFS it is not capable of using LINUX permissions.  If it is EXT make sure you set the disk to you as an owner and group using `sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/{device/`

Comment: Where did the disk come from? Windows? Are you capable of using the command line? Diagnosis/Solution is easier there.

Comment: If it is an ntfs drive, then the file system might not be clean, in which case it is not automatically mounted. Have the drive checked under MS Windows and disconnect properly (or have Windows fully shut down - no faststart!).

Comment: Perhaps I should have added this information:  I have two computers, both running the latest UBUNTU mate 20.04. It acts normally on one, showing up in all dialogues correctly. But on this other computer, it mounts (as I said, it shows up properly on the left side when I open a folder), but I can't access it in Save As or Open File dialogues and can't change permissions for the directory / media.

Comment: Yes, to the question if I can use the command line and yes, to the question if the HD was originally used in Windows. But, as I said, I've been using it in Linux for years on a different computer with no problems.